# Correct PHP Syntax

Tags: php, html

I need to add this HTML tag:

```php
<img src = "<?php echo esc_url( get_avatar_url( $post->post_author ) ); ?>" />
```

Inside PHP:

```php
echo '<h3 class="nome-vendor-cat">',
    $current_cat->name,
    "&nbsp;di&nbsp;",
    '<a href="' . $vendor_link->get_shop_url() . '" class="nome-vendor">',
    get_usermeta( $post->post_author, 'dokan_store_name' ),
    '</span>',
    '</h3>';
```

I have to insert that image in PHP, but it always generates syntax errors.

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting within your post?

Comment: if you replace those `$current_cat->name`, `$vendor_link->get_shop_url()` and `get_usermeta( $post->post_author, 'dokan_store_name' )` with literals, it just works. So maybe there's something wrong with those? Maybe also writing what's the syntax error thrown.. evaluating if those variables are set.. and so on. Make some effort please

Comment: Also a quick tip, when your `<?php` statement only contains an `echo`, you can use the shorthand `<?=` instead: `<?= esc_url(get_avatar_url( $post->post_author)); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on:

```
<img src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_avatar_url($post->post_author));?>" />
```

Detect the **PHP** part:

```
esc_url(get_avatar_url($post->post_author))
```

Detect the **HTML** part:

```
<img src = "
//and
" />
```

Write it in **PHP**:

```
echo '<img src = "'.esc_url(get_avatar_url($post->post_author)).'" />';
```

And you should better use `.` for concating things.
Its ok to use `,` when you `echo` stuff.
But if you replace `echo` with an assignment `$var =` , you have to replace all `,` with `.` to get it work again.
So always use `.`.